# Metric to measure number of subsequences of size >=2 that occur in two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose I have 2 strings of equal length. I am looking for a metric to measure how much the two strings are closely related in terms of the number of sub sequences that they both have that have size >=2.

For example, suppose `x="ABCDEF"`, and `y="DEFABC"`. In these two strings, the sub sequences `"ABC"`, `"DEF"`, `"AB"`, `"BC"`, `"DE"`, `"EF"` are all inner sub sequences with `size >=2` and occur in both strings.

Is there any metric, or non-naive algorithm that would measure how many of these patterns occur in two strings?

Comment: I'm affraid that the only thing that you can do is checking all 2^n sequences (n is the length of the string ). what's the maximum length of the string ? if n <= 25 such algorithm is acceptable.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb n can unfortunately range up to 100.

Comment: By a sequence you mean a contiguous sequence? in that case it's more easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *suffix tree* / *suffix array* for this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

for the example provided in the question in case of *suffix array* implementation you'll have

```
ABCDEF -> $  
          ABCDEF$
          BCDEF$
          CDEF$
          DEF$
          EF$
          F$

($ marks end of string)
```

suffix array which allows you using *binary search* for the other string's *n-grams*. Let's test n-grams for the `"DEFABC"` over the suffix array:

```
 "DE"   - found (DEF$), countinue to longer n-gram (3-gram)
 "DEF"  - found (DEF$), countinue to longer n-gram (4-gram)
 "DEFA" - failed, continue to next 2-gram
 "EF"   - found (EF$), countinue to longer n-gram (3-gram) 
 "EFA"  - failed, continue to next 2-gram
 "FA"   - failed, continue to next 2-gram
 "AB"   - found (ABCDEF$), countinue to longer n-gram (3-gram)
 "ABC"  - found (ABCDEF$), end of string reached, continue to next 2-gram
 "BC"   - found (BCDEF$), end of string reached
```

`6` common *n-grams* (`n >= 2`) are found.

So far so good for the string of length `N` we've spent `O(N*log(N))` to create *suffix array* and `O(N*log(N))` to scan for *n-grams* (`O(N)` to scan, `O(log(N))` to look in the suffix array); *suffix tree* being more difficult to implement wants just `O(N)` to be created.

In general case, when you check strings of size `M` and `N` the complexity will be `O(M*log(M) + N*log(M))` in case of *suffix array* and `O(M) + N*log(M)` in case of *suffix tree*.

Sample **C#** code

```
  string left = "ABCDEF";
  string right = "DEFABCD";
  int n = 2;

  // Very memory inefficient implementation, wants about N*N bytes per string
  // just to demo
  string[] array = Enumerable
    .Range(0, left.Length)                  // all possible ...
    .Select(index => left.Substring(index)) // ... suffixes which are ...
    .OrderBy(suffix => suffix)              // ... ordered as ...
    .ToArray();                             // ... array

  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i <= right.Length - n; ++i) {
    for (int length = n; length <= right.Length - i; ++length) {
      string toFind = right.Substring(i, length);

      int index = Array.BinarySearch(array, toFind);

      if (index >= 0) { // exact match
        if (toFind != array[index])
          break;
      }
      else { // prefix match
        int idx = ~index;

        if (!(idx < left.Length && array[idx].StartsWith(toFind)) || 
             (idx >= 1 && array[idx - 1].StartsWith(toFind)))
          break;
      }

      count += 1;
    }
  }

  Console.Write(count); // the output is "6"
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the sample code. Accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is simple O(n^3) solution, first for each string extract all sequences and store them ( inside a map for example ) using 3 nested loop i(1..n) j(1..i) k (j..i) and make sure that the length of each sequence is >= 2, now iterate the 2 stored sequences and count the number of occur.

**UPD**

Here's a pseudo Java code :

```
        char[] s1 = next().toCharArray();
        HashMap<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
                if(i-j>=2) {
                    String sub = "";
                    for(int k=j;k<=i;k++)
                        sub+=s1[k]; // Instead use String builder to concat 2 strings because concating using String class in Java is O(n)
                    if(map1.get(sub) == null)
                        map1.put(sub,0);
                    map1.put(sub,map1.get(sub)+1);

                }
        for(String sub:map1.keySet())
            out.println(sub + " " +map1.get(sub));
```

Do the same for the 2 string and count the number of occur.